# Is my relay logic practicable?

Tags: relay, switching, induction-motor

I am trying to apply relay logic to control my machine. The schematic is as shown.

[image]

'R' is a relay.

Please note that my schematic symbols may not be the symbols used in industry.

Wanted outcome: `Motor 1` should run until it hits the limit switch. When it hits the limit switch, the relay should switch off and `Motor 2` should power on.

Concerns: I am concerned that the relay and `Motor 2` will receive current simultaneously when current is first applied. So, I am not sure if `Motor 2` will try to move until the relay is switched to closed position. I am not sure if I have made myself clear and am willing to elaborate if required.

Please note that these are AC motors.

Comment: How or when does motor 2 stop?  How do you reset the system to the starting configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the schematic.

It is presumed that the motors 'M1' and 'M2' respectively actuate and release the limit switch at the end of their traverse.

[image]

The motor 'M1' starts when SPST switch 'S1' is closed. It stops when the limit switch is actuated and the relay is energised to start motor 'M2'. Motor 'M2' stops when the limit switch is released and the cycle continues.

The problem you have anticipated is avoided.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This resolves my issue and thanks for the clear diagram!

Comment: Anytime! I'm glad my answer was helpful.